# How can you explain the shape of the W mass peak in a transverse mass plot in the case of WZ production

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics

I'm looking for events where a W and a Z boson is produced from collision of two protons, with backgrounds coming from top-antitop production, production of 2 Z bosons and Drell-Yann processes (production of 1 Z boson). Selections have been made to reduce these backgrounds.

Plotted here is the transverse mass of the missing transverse momentum (i.e. the neutrino from W decay) and the lepton associated with the W boson.

[image: W Mass resonance]

I'm unsure how to explain the shape of the WZ component. Why is there a flat, somewhat constant part in the beginning and a 'normal' but fairly wide resonance at the W boson mass? The transverse mass is an intuitively difficult concept for me so it's a hard to draw conclusions myself... I've tried looking it up online but I mostly find plots with a Jacobian peak, which looks nothing what I have.
I also see a very slight increase of the ttbar background around 80 GeV (which I've confirmed on another plot). Is this an anomaly or can it be explained?

Comment: You have to compare it with the equivalent monte carlo data. If you want to search deeper reasons check the monte carlo data.

Comment: The coloured parts are the Monte Carlo simulations

Comment: so what is your problem then? if the monte carlo fits the data,? It means that the physics model used is correct, and you can go to the event generator and see what is the physics model used if you are that interested.

Comment: This plot (and the others) are simply reproductions I've made from an existing paper to get started with ROOT. I had access to data and MC simulations that were created for me. I'm writing a report on it and I'd like to explain the various features of the graphs.

Comment: imo the only explanation lies in looking at the basic physics formulas inputs to the montecarlo. It is a multiparameter problem that  *needs* the monte carlo. There one can see which interactions dominate where, and how they might add in order to give the observed peak. I think the monte carlo fit itself is the explanation.

Comment: note that the transverse mass has a limiting form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_mass   "The distribution of M_T  has an end-point at the invariant mass M  of the system with M T ≤ M  *This has been used to determine the W mass at the Tevatron*.  Hand waving one can explain the peaking by the increasing energy entering the invariant mass system reaching a peak at the real mass, and then falling when no longer containing decay products of the large WZ masses.